# ionic + typescript .ts isn't converted to .js

Tags: node.js, cordova, typescript, ionic-framework

I created an blank ionic app with npm:

```
ionic start myapp blank
```

then I changed to the app directory, and set the platform to windows:

```
cd myapp
ionic platform windows
```

So far everything is fine, but when I open the Project in visualstudio to add some .ts files they won't be compiled to the .js files.
I there something I have forgotten?

Comment: Did you install https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2d42d8dc-e085-45eb-a30b-3f7d50d55304 ?

Comment: Yes I did. When I create a simple typescript project with visualstudio everything works as expected.

Comment: Try to find in your simple typescript project file (.csproj) section that builds typescript and copy paste into your `ionic` application